# Create a scoped block in rails helper for additional scoped methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, block, helper

I would like to define some helper methods within a block helper but keep them within the scope of the block so that I can have sensible method names and it looks cleaner.

Say I want to do the following (a very basic example), in my view using helpers:

```
<%= foo_box do |b| %>
    <%= b.title( 'Foo Bar' ) %>
    Lorem Ipsum...
<% end %>
```

To produce something like

```
<div class="foo_box">
   <h2>Foo Bar</h2>
   Lorem Ipsum...
</div>
```

This way I could also have a `bar_box` block helper which could also have a `title` method which outputs something totally different.

Currently I have them implemented as different methods, e.g. `foo_box` and `foo_box_title`, with `foo_box` handling the block like so:

```
def foo_box(&block)
  content_tag(:div, capture(&block), :class => 'foo_box')
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the looks of it, `capture` doesn't let you pass any arguments into the block, which you want to do. The argument to bass in (`b`) has to be an object of some sort that you define the `title` etc. methods on. So, lets define a helper class which will output the stuff you need, and pass it to the block passed in from the view, and then capture it and surround it in the `div` as you did above. I would do something like this:

```
class FooBoxHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper  
  def title(text)
    content_tag(:h2, text)
  end
  def small(text)
    content_tag(:p, text, :class => "small")
  end
end

def foo_box(&block)

  new_block = Proc.new do 
    helper = FooBoxHelper.new
    block.call(helper)
  end
  content_tag(:div, capture(&new_block), :class => 'foo_box')
end
```

See how I got around the limitation of the `capture` method? By binding a new Proc to the current scope, and passing in the helper object there, we get a block we can call with no arguments, and thus acceptable by `capture`. Also, make certain your helper class includes all the relevant helper methods from `ActionView::Helpers`. Hope this helps!